# python regex optional capture group question

Tags: python, regex

I have the following problem matching, the data like below:

```
LABEL: TEXT1 TEXT2
```

The "LABEL" and "TEXT2" is optional, and separate by "\s"(blank or indent).

I would like to have 3 capture groups giving as output :

```
group1:LABEL(or None)
group2:TEXT1
group3:TEXT2(or None)
```

So I've written a regex like this :

```
\s*(\S*(?::))?\s*(\S*)\s*(.*$)
```

And the result is:

```
group1:LABEL:
group2:TEXT1
group3:TEXT2(or Null)
```

The problem is why group1 contain ":"?

And when TEXT2 doesn't exist, group3 is null instead of None

Comment: Did any answer help? If you need more assistance please let know.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this approach:

```py
inp = ["LABEL: TEXT1 TEXT2", "LABEL: TEXT1", "TEXT1 TEXT2", "TEXT1"]
matches = [re.findall(r'(?:(\w+):)?\s*(\w+)(?:\s+(\w+))?', x) for x in inp]
print(matches)

# [[('LABEL', 'TEXT1', 'TEXT2')],
   [('LABEL', 'TEXT1', '')],
   [('', 'TEXT1', 'TEXT2')],
   [('', 'TEXT1', '')]]
```

This regex pattern says to match:

```regex
(?:(\w+):)?    an optional leading word term followed by colon
\s*            optional whitespace
(\w+)          mandatory middle word term
(?:\s+(\w+))?  optional space followed a final word term
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but what about if "TEXT2" might contain "\s"(blank or indent)?  For instance, TEXT2='HELLO WORLD'

Comment: I have answered the question which was asked.  If you needed something else, then you asked the wrong question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
^(?:(.*?):)?\s*(\S+)(?:\s+(\S.*))?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LyTpZl/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:(.*?):)?` - an optional sequence of any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible captured into Group 1 and then a `:` char
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(\S+)` - Group 2: one or more non-whitespace chars
- `(?:\s+(\S.*))?` - an optional sequence of one or more whitespaces and then Group 3 capturing a non-whitespace and then any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `$` - end of string

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/GJ5zPI):

```py
import re
texts = ['L A B12 E4L-0: TEXT1 TEXT 2 HEL-L!O!!!', 'TEXT1 TEXT 2 HEL-L!O!!!', 'L A B12 E4L-0: TEXT1', 'TEXT']
rx = re.compile(r'^(?:(.*?):)?\s*(\S+)(?:\s+(\S.*))?$')
for text in texts:
    m = rx.search(text)
    if m:
        print(m.groups())
```

Output:

```
('L A B12 E4L-0', 'TEXT1', 'TEXT 2 HEL-L!O!!!')
(None, 'TEXT1', 'TEXT 2 HEL-L!O!!!')
('L A B12 E4L-0', 'TEXT1', None)
(None, 'TEXT', None)
```