# How to create optional capture groups in Python regex

Tags: python, regex

I have examined [a previous question relating to optional capture groups in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70616334/python-regex-optional-capture-group-question), but this has not been helpful.  Attempting to follow, the code I have is below:

```py
import re
c = re.compile(r'(?P<Prelude>.*?)'
               r'(?:Discussion:(?P<Discussion>.+?))?'
               r'(?:References:(?P<References>.*?))?',
               re.M|re.S)

test_text = r"""Prelude strings
Discussion: this is some
text.

References:  My bad, I have none.
"""

test_text2 = r"""Prelude strings
Discussion: this is some
text.
"""

print(c.match(test_text).groups())
print(c.match(test_text2).groups())
```

Both print `('Prelude strings', None, None)` instead of capturing the two groups.  I am unable to determine why.

The expected result is `('Prelude strings', ' this is some\ntext.', '  My bad, I have none.')` for the first, and the second the same but with `None` as the third capture group.  It should also be possible to delete the `Discussion` lines and still capture `References`.

Comment: I think you want `(?s)^(?P<Prelude>.*?)(?:Discussion:\s*(?P<Discussion>.*?)\s*)?(?:References:\s*(?P<References>.*?))?$`, see https://regex101.com/r/UdQrb0/1. Remove `re.M` in your code when using the pattern (and `(?s)` is the equivalent of `re.S`)

Comment: That solves it, curious why re.M was the problem.  I'm parsing the PDF for NIST SP 800-53 because I'm too lazy to associate 400 pages of controls by hand to controls from a security audit in a report document, so this is a life saver.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
c = re.compile(r'^(?P<Prelude>.*?)'
               r'(?:Discussion:\s*(?P<Discussion>.*?)\s*)?'
               r'(?:References:\s*(?P<References>.*?))?$',
               re.S)
```

One-line regex pattern as a string:

```
(?s)^(?P<Prelude>.*?)(?:Discussion:\s*(?P<Discussion>.*?)\s*)?(?:References:\s*(?P<References>.*?))?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UdQrb0/1).

*Details*:

- `(?s)` - same as `re.S`, makes `.` match line break chars
- `^` - start of the whole string (note that it no longer matches start of any line, since I removed the `re.M` flag)
- `(?P<Prelude>.*?)` - Group "Prelude": any zero or more chars as few as possible
- `(?:Discussion:\s*(?P<Discussion>.*?)\s*)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching one or zero occurrences of the following sequence:

  - `Discussion:` - a fixed string
  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
  - `(?P<Discussion>.*?)` - Group "Discussion": zero or more chars as few as possible
  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(?:References:\s*(?P<References>.*?))?` - an optional non-capturing group matching one or zero occurrences of the following sequence:

  - `References:` - a fixed string
  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
  - `(?P<References>.*?)` - Group "References": any zero or more chars as few as possible
- `$` - end of the string.